# Year month sum in a row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with values per day and customer and I want to list all customers group by month but each row is a customer with the last 12 months:

Example

```
Customer   Date          Quantity
---------------------------------
cname-AA   2021/03/01    10
cname-AA   2021/03/02    20
cname-AA   2021/04/01    20
cname-AA   2021/04/02    20

cname-BB   2021/03/01    15
cname-BB   2021/03/02    25
cname-BB   2021/04/01    15
cname-BB   2021/04/02    35
```

expected result:

```
Customer     2021-03    2021-04
-----------------------------------
cname-AA     30          40
cname-BB     40          50
```

I know how to group by customer and month and filter the last 12 months. My difficulty is to return the months total as columns.

Comment: The SQL language has a strict requirement for the number and names of columns to be known ahead of time, _before_ looking at any data. What you're asking for is for the columns to be dynamic. That usually involves a pivot in the client code or reporting tool.

Answer (score 1):

If you expect the columns to be structured as you described, one way to achieve this could be using [`PIVOT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15) and dynamic SQL.

The `PIVOT` function allows you to convert rows into columns, whereas dynamic SQL provides flexibility to generate the column names (e.g, the start of the months in your example) dynamically. Especially if the query is meant to aggregate data over an unknown time period.

This approach also enables the data to drive the output. Such that the more dates you specify, the query should output as expected.

```
CREATE TABLE #CustomerTable (Customer VARCHAR(20), [Date] DATETIME, Quantity INT)
INSERT INTO #CustomerTable VALUES
('cname-AA','2021/03/01',10),('cname-AA','2021/03/02',20),('cname-AA','2021/04/01',20),('cname-AA','2021/04/02',20),
('cname-BB','2021/03/01',15),('cname-BB','2021/03/02',25),('cname-BB','2021/04/01',15),('cname-BB','2021/04/02',35)

-- stores dynamically generated months from dataset and the query to execute
DECLARE @Months AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
DECLARE @Query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

-- setup the months to PIVOT on
SELECT @Months = @Months + QUOTENAME(MonthStart) + ',' 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), ct.[Date], 126)  AS MonthStart
      FROM #CustomerTable ct) as tmp
SELECT @Months = SUBSTRING(@Months, 0, LEN(@Months))

SET @Query = '
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT ct.Customer,
           CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), ct.[Date], 126) AS MonthStart,
           ct.Quantity
    FROM #CustomerTable ct
    ) AS Src
    PIVOT (
        SUM(Quantity)
        FOR MonthStart IN (' + @Months + ')
    )   AS PivotTable';

EXECUTE(@Query)

DROP TABLE #CustomerTable
```

Output:

| Customer | 2021-03 | 2021-04 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| cname-AA | 30 | 40 |
| cname-BB | 40 | 50 |

Answer (score 0):

If you have only dates, and no times, as you have in the example.  This query should work:

```
SELECT CUSTOMER, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN DATE BETWEEN '2021-03-01 00:00:00' AND '2021-03-31 00:00:00' THEN QUANTITY ELSE 0 END) MAR21,
  SUM(CASE WHEN DATE BETWEEN '2021-04-01 00:00:00' AND '2021-04-30 00:00:00' THEN QUANTITY ELSE 0 END) APR21
FROM TABLE1
GROUP BY CUSTOMER
```

Here's the fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0da73c/4

To use this, you'll need more columns in your case, 10 more for each month.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use conditional aggregation:

```
select customer,
       sum(case when month(date) = 3 then quantity end) as mar,
       sum(case when month(date) = 4 then quantity end) as apr
from t
group by customer;
```

It is unclear if you need a `where` clause to limit this to a particular period of time, such as:

```
where date >= '2021-03-01' and date < '2021-05-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't match the output that you wanted, but I wanted  to show you an alternative that would be more dynamic, meaning you don't have to "Hard Code" the month and year in your query.

```
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT Customer, DATEPART(YEAR, DateTime2Field) As MyYear, DATEPART(Month, DateTime2Field) AS MyMonth,Quantity
FROM MyTable
)

SELECT Customer, CONCAT(MyYear, '-', MyMonth) AS [Year-Month], SUM(Quantity) AS SummedQuantiy
FROM CTE
GROUP BY Customer, MyYear, MyMonth
ORDER BY Customer, MyYear, MyMonth
```